# Javascript Proxy fails with instantiation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy

I have a proxied object where I intercept get(). If the requested attribute does not exist then I load it from a script. That part works fine. But if a class is referenced then the instantiation goes ahead before the value gets loaded. **The obvious answer is to use callbacks**, but I can't find a way to intercept the construct() operation or some other means to hook in a callback to delay the instantiation process until the script load fully completes.

I do understand callbacks, fetch(), import() but the answers relating to any of those do not address the race condition when using Proxied objects.

The following has been tested with Chrome v71.  I am not interested in compatability with other browsers, nor the use of jQuery or any other framework.  I would have thought that ES6 functionality would suffice.

The module that I will attempt to load:

```js
App.User = class {
    constructor(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    show() {
        console.log(`Hello, I am ${this._name}.`);
    }
}
```

The web page and script causing the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Script Loading</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> A test for dynamic script loading</p>
<script>

App = {};

function loadScript(url) {
  console.log(`loadScript: loading ${url}`);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = false;
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = () => {
        console.log(`loadScript: loaded ${url}`);
        resolve(script);
    }
    script.onerror = () => reject(new Error("Script load error: " + url));
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    console.log(`loadScript: loading ${url}`);
  });
}

var hdlApp = {
    get: function(obj, prop) {
        if (prop in obj) {
            console.log(`App has property ${prop}`);
            return obj[prop];
        } else {
            console.log(`App does NOT have property ${prop}`);
            loadScript(`${prop}.js`).then(
                val => {
                    console.log('THEN');
                    return obj[prop]
                },
                err => {
                    console.log('CATCH');
                    return undefined;
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
window.App = new Proxy({}, hdlApp);

function test() {
    console.log('First test');
    u1 = new App.User('Fred');
    u1.show();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On the first test, the `new App.User` gets executed before the script has fully loaded.  On a second attempt the script has fully loaded & compiled so it works.  Which proves that the Proxy get() part is fine.  I just don't know how to delay the constructor invocation until the script is fully loaded.

[image: Running with DevTools console yields the following:]

Comment: It will never work this way.

Comment: None of the claimed duplicate answers relate to the above question.  Could you please remove the duplicate annotation.

Comment: Have edited the question.  If the example worked I wouldn't be asking the question.  I think the problem is specific to needing to intercept the instantiation process and I can't see how that can be done with a callback.

Comment: Your `App.User` evaluates to `undefined` because your `else` branch does not return anything. Returning `obj[prop]` is an entirely unrelated return within the nested function. You could ditch the Promise entirely, but either way sync XHR is an extremely bad idea and means this design approach is too.

Comment: If you really want dynamic module loading, look into existing systems like AMD modules.